# Bank database program

Tags: python

I have been trying to improve my Python coding and was just wondering if there was a more pythonic way to perform what I have done so far, namely around the date in the `main()` function.

```
import datetime
import sybase

account_list = []

def get_date(): # Date -1 day unless Monday then -3 days
    d = datetime.date.today()
    if d.weekday() == 0:
        date = d - datetime.timedelta(days=3)
        return date
    else:
        date = d - datetime.timedelta(days=1)
        return date


def get_unique_accounts(date):
    conn = sybase.Connection('')
    c = conn.cursor()
    c.execute("SELECT DISTINCT acct from accounts WHERE date = @date", {"@date": date})
    result = c.fetchall()
    for row in result:
        account_list.append(row[0])
    c.close()
    conn.close()


def check_balance(date):
    conn = sybase.Connection('')
    c = conn.cursor()
    c.execute("SELECT TOP 1 name,balance from balance WHERE date = @date", {"@date": date})
    result = c.fetchone()
    c.close()
    conn.close()
    return result


def main():
    date = get_date()
    get_unique_accounts(date) # This will be used for future functions
    check_balance(date)
    

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: Sybase, though? Why?

Comment: I have no control over the current in place DB solution :(

Comment: That's deeply unfortunate. For your own learning purposes, if you have the opportunity I suggest trying out PostgreSQL instead of a museum piece.

Comment: You've tagged this as both Python 2 and 3. What are the constraints? Does the `sybase` package work with 3?

Comment: I will do for sure, as I've used MySQL and variants when I did PHP coding. But as for what I've posted above is there a more 'pythonic' method? Or have I done all I can so far correctly. We have a modified sybase module that we can import for both 2 and 3.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will focus on the `get_date()` method. First of all, what sort of date is it? Currently the name makes me think it will get the current date, but it's sort of a banking date? Something along the lines of `get_last_banking_day()` would be more descriptive?

You can move the return to the end of the function as that is the same in both blocks of the if/else:

```
def get_last_banking_day(): # Date -1 day unless Monday then -3 days
    d = datetime.date.today()

    if d.weekday() == 0:
        date = d - datetime.timedelta(days=3)
    else:
        date = d - datetime.timedelta(days=1)
    
    return date
```

You could clean up the import and only import the 2 things needed from `datetime`, `date` and `timedelta`.:

```
from datetime import date, timedelta
```

The function would become:

```
def get_last_banking_day(): # Date -1 day unless Monday then -3 days
    d = date.today()

    if d.weekday() == 0:
        date = d - timedelta(days=3)
    else:
        date = d - timedelta(days=1)
    
    return date
```

Now we can look at variable names and do some cleanup, especially the `d` variable. Always try to avoid non-descriptive names:

```
def get_last_banking_day(): # Date -1 day unless Monday then -3 days
    today = date.today()

    if today.weekday() == 0:
        last_banking_day = today - timedelta(days=3)
    else:
        last_banking_day = today - timedelta(days=1)
    
    return last_banking_day
```

As the `today - timedelta(days=1)` is the default we use it as such and set the value to this and only use an if-statement to set the exception:

```
def get_last_banking_day(): # Date -1 day unless Monday then -3 days
    today = date.today()
    last_banking_day = today - timedelta(days=1)

    if today.weekday() == 0:
        last_banking_day = today - timedelta(days=3)

    return last_banking_day
```

Comment: AH thanks Korfoo, the if loop where there is already a default is mistake I need to remove from my mindset when coding. Although just for reference you still have 'return date' rather than 'return 'last_banking_day'

Comment: Oops, I edited it to correct the return. Do note that I only looked at the `get_date` method as I do not have experience with `sybase` so I can not give tips about that :)

Comment: Appreciate it, I do not think there are improvements that could be made elsewhere in what has been posted.